# Estou com problemas para conectar o codeigniter no oracle

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter-3

Estou com dois problemas ao configurar a conexão com oracle.

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Use of undefined constant OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS - assumed 'OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS'

Filename: database/DB.php

Line Number: 201

Backtrace:

File: C:\Users\willian.nascimento\Desktop\projeto\Teste\Source\Release\application\third_party\MX\Loader.php
Line: 109
Function: DB

File: C:\Users\willian.nascimento\Desktop\projeto\Teste\Source\Release\application\third_party\MX\Loader.php
Line: 65
Function: initialize

File: C:\Users\willian.nascimento\Desktop\projeto\Teste\Source\Release\application\third_party\MX\Base.php
Line: 55
Function: __construct

File: C:\Users\willian.nascimento\Desktop\projeto\Teste\Source\Release\application\third_party\MX\Base.php
Line: 60
Function: __construct

File: C:\Users\willian.nascimento\Desktop\projeto\Teste\Source\Release\application\third_party\MX\Controller.php
Line: 4
Function: require

File: C:\Users\willian.nascimento\Desktop\projeto\Teste\Source\Release\application\third_party\MX\Modules.php
Line: 123
Function: include_once

File: C:\Users\willian.nascimento\Desktop\projeto\Teste\Source\Release\application\modules\contrato\controllers\Contrato.php
Line: 4
Function: spl_autoload_call

File: C:\Users\willian.nascimento\Desktop\projeto\Teste\Source\Release\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once


Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in C:\Users\willian.nascimento\Desktop\projeto\Teste\Source\Release\system\database\drivers\oci8\oci8_driver.php on line 238
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Error

Message: Call to undefined function oci_connect()

Filename: oci8/oci8_driver.php

Line Number: 238

Backtrace:
```

Estou usando o codeigniter 3.

Obs: já verifiquei meu php.ini e desabilitei somente as extensões relacionadas ao oci8 e também já verifiquei se essas dlls estão na pasta ext.

***Meu phpinfo()***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tem o oracle client na maquina que esta usando ?

Comment: @Otto esse oracle client que você está falando é esse `instantclient_12_2`? Se for sim está na minha máquina.

Comment: paths configurados ? no phpinfo aparece a extenção oci8 ?

Comment: Então @Otto acho que sim mas por via da dúvida atualizei a pergunta com o `phpinfo()` do meu `php.ini`.

Comment: OCI 8 não esta sendo carregado, teria de ver nos logs do php o que ta ocorrendo

Comment: @Otto onde posso ver esses logs?

Comment: da uma olhada no google para ver certinho no seu sistema

Comment: @Otto vi nos logs e agora o erro é esse aqui: `Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_oci' (tried: C:\php\ext\pdo_oci (NÒo foi possÝvel encontrar o m¾dulo especificado.
), C:\php\ext\php_pdo_oci.dll (NÒo foi possÝvel encontrar o m¾dulo especificado.
)) in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: entao da uma olhada nesse link http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/technote-php-instant-12c-2088811.html